# How to Upgrade CentOS 7.x to RHEL 8.x by disconnected method or without subscription and how?

Tags: centos, rhel, upgrade, migration

I have a CentOS distribution and I want to migrate/ Upgrade it in RHEL 7 but I don't have a subscription so, it can be possible to migrate it without subscription.

Comment: What is the purpose of this system?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.